# EF context changes not saving

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework

Very basic scenario.  I have a context attached to a db with one table that has one row in it.  I can bind ui to the data and see data just fine, but changes, additions, etc do not save.   Below is a 5 line bit that does not result in any changes to the db.  Curious and confused.

```
        var context = new TestEntities();
        context .DataItems.Load();  // Testing - already one row in the table.
        context .DataItems.First().Data = "Blah Blah Blah";
        context .DataItems.Add(new DataItem() { Data = "Happy Birthday" });
        context .SaveChanges();
```

The data in the database does not change.  No new row.  No updated row.

Connection:
  <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string="data source=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.sdf"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

I'm sure this is something stupid, but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you provide more details, any error/exception you are getting on this? You can use addTo_Object to add new records into the table.

Comment: It's not something silly like your source database is begin copied every time you compile, overriding your changes, is it?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: Got back to this after a day full of meetings.  I changed the database to a server based database and it works fine.  Something about the sdf db is horky.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

try doing it as below:-

```
context .DataItems.AddObject(new DataItem() { Data = "Happy Birthday" });
```